# Though vs While

Tags: conjunctions

> While he thinks the phenomenon is the result of enzyme action, I believe it is caused by a shortage of neurotransmitter.

According to SAT, here *while* is wrong, it should be *though*. As far as I know *while* is interchangeable with *though* in many cases.

Is *while* wrong here?

Comment: I think you have been had. http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/although-versus-while

Answer (score 4):

SAT rules require test takers in the Verbal sections to weigh the answers and compare two good answers. Two plus two is four, but in language, there are shades of meaning that the College Board tests. One answer may be suitable, while another  is superior.

In your sentence, *while* serves the sentence but *though* does a better job. *While* means that at the moment of your judgements, your opinions were not identical as to the cause. *Though* emphasizes that your opinions oppose each other, which they do. That reasoning makes it the answer the test seeks. *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fifth edition, offers the following information:

[Usage note for **while**:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/while)

> As a conjunction, while is used to indicate that two events are happening at the same time … .

[A definition for **though**:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/though)

> 1. Despite the fact that; although.

Comment: The same dictionary defines *while* as *although*. The question should be thrown out of the test.

Comment: -1 The same usage note reads *While has been used in this nontemporal sense for hundreds of years, and the latter sentence was judged acceptable by 75 percent of the Usage Panel in our 2012 survey.*